# Why is Google hiding the search input field?

Tags: google-search, google-chrome

For some reason, Google search is hiding the input field in Chrome and using the URL field as the search parameters. Is there a way I can disable this feature?

How I don't like it:

[image: how i don't like it]

How I would like it:

[image: How i like it]

Also, the weird thing is that it is not consistent, it somehow only happens at work and not when I am home.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Happens to me that way too:   work is Win 7.    Home is Win 8.1

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal my OS on my latop is Win 7 x64, It happens only at work. When i bring my laptop home it does not happen. Also have not seen it happen on my desktop.

Comment: I think this falls under the "Browsers and their features relating to the use of a web application" category, so I'm inclined to leave it here for the time being.  However, if there's precedent for this type of question on Super User, I'm willing to move it.

Comment: Errr...Google Search has worked like that for ages, at least in Chrome.

Comment: I'm actually noticing this behaviour myself, but it seems totally at random. I usually get the search field on the page, but once or twice today, the search field is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I see what the pattern is.

1. Browsing to http://www.google.com, and entering my search terms in the search field, *always* gives a result page with a search field
2. Entering my search term in Chrome's address bar and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> gives a result page with a search field
3. Entering my search term in Chrome's address bar, and selectinga previous search or a Google suggestion, gives a search result page *without* a search field

Note that for scenario 2 and 3, it is not easy to distinguish between entering a search term and pressing enter, and entering a search term and selecting from the suggestion list. Pay close attention to which keys you are pressing, and to what is selected when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In order to invoke scenario 2, I must press <kbd>Enter</kbd> immediately, before the suggestion list pops up.

It also seems to matter if I'm already displaying a Google search result page. If so, the next results page seems to always include the search field.